# Extraer un código de un texto

Tags: r, regex

Quiero extraer `A06664635`  de

```
tex <- c("2566751 rttLE A PAUPPTAD","QWERTY20175499 A06664635 TAGO OJ 75%")
```

Mi lógica es: extraer todo lo q tenga ESPACIO-1LETRA-NUMEROS

```
str_extract(tex, "\\s[A-Z]\\d*")
```

y obtengo:

```
[1] " A"         " A06664635"
```

Obtengo lo que quiero aunque con un espacio delante que tendré que quitar (" A06664635")
pero no sé por qué saco también la " A"

EDITO: probando

```
str_extract(tex, "\\s[A-Z]\\d+")
```

No sé por que con un + si lo saca y con un * no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las expresión `*` significa básicamente hacer coincidir el patrón anterior (`\d`) de 0 a ilimitadas veces, por lo que la ausencia de números entra en las posibles coincidencias, por el contrario `+` pide coincidir al menos una vez a ilimitadas veces.

Te sugiero además un patrón un poco más especifico y capturar directamente el dato:

```
str_match(tex, "\\s([A-Z]{1}\\d+)\\s")
```

En este caso esperamos:

- `\\s`: espacios
- `[A-Z]{1}`: 1 letra
- `\\d+`: 1 o más números (si el tamaño es fijo sugiero especificar un máximo)
- `\\s`: espacios

Answer (score 0):

En este caso lo que haría sería combiar `str_extract` con `str_trim`. Esta funcion permite eliminar los espacios en blanco al principio y final de un string.

```
str_trim(str_extract(tex, "\\s[A-Z]\\d*")) 

 "A"         "A06664635"
```